# Firebase database returns wrong data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-filterable

In firebase database I am having a node named userDetails where I am storing user related data. In android while fetching current user data, it returns correct values for first time. Now after sign out again when a new user login, it returns the previous users data. Here is my code:

```
mCurrentUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userDetails").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
mCurrentUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot != null){
                if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                    mUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    if (mUser != null) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

In application class

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);
}
```

Can any one help me to figure out this issue.

Below is my database structure

```
-userDetails
    - uid1
        - name
        - phone
        etc.
    - uid2
        - name
        - phone
        etc.
    - uid3
        - name
        - phone
        etc.
```

Comment: can you please share your firebase database structure?

Comment: Yes. Added please check.

Comment: @SureshKumar Why do you saing "it returns the previous users data"? How do you read data? Please add the code that you are using to read data and responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo The userDetails is a arrayList where each users data are stored using the respective UID. I am retrieving using the FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(). This works file when the app launched for first time. After sign out when a new user try to login, it returns the previous users data. Something wrong with the Firebase database api.

Comment: show us your logout code please

Comment: @SureshKumar Please add the code that you are using to read data and your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have already added the code and database structure above.

Comment: @MohammadRbabah my logout code is FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

Comment: @SureshKumar You say `userDetails is a arrayList` I cannot see any array in your structure. Please provide it as a JSON or as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo you can see above I have mentioned the database structure. uid1, uid2 and uid3 are elements of the userDetails node in firebase database.